# Несовместимые типы string и pointer

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Не могу понять в чем проблема, помогите пожалуйста

```
incompatible types 'Task2.Char' and 'System.Char'
incompatible types 'string' and 'pointer'
```

Указывает на строки 43-51 :

```
begin
  GetMem(p, 32*1024); // Подготовка буфера
  GetWindowText(hMemo, p, 32*1024);
  Move(#13#10, PChar(Integer(p) + Length(p))^, 2);
  GetWindowText(hEdit, PChar(Integer(p + Length(p))), 32*1024);
  SetWindowText(hMemo, p);
  while (LOWORD(SendMessage(hMemo, EM_SCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN,0))<> 0) do;
  FreeMem(p); // Освобождение буфера
end;
```

//////

```
program Task2;

uses
  Windows,
  Messages;
var
  hButton    : HWND;
  hMemo      : HWND;
  hEdit      : HWND;
const
  id_Button = 100;
  id_Edit = 100;
  cw_UseDefault = 200;

function WindowProc(hWnd: THandle; uMsg, wParam, lParam: Integer): Integer;
stdcall;
export;
{функция окна}
var
p: ^Char; // Буфер для считывания строки
begin
  Result := 0;
    case uMsg of
    WM_DESTROY:
        halt(0);
    WM_CREATE: begin
      // create button
      hButton := CreateWindowEx(0,'BUTTON','&click on me',
        ws_Child or ws_Visible or bs_PushButton, 10, 100, 200, 80, hWnd,
        id_Button, hInstance, nil);
      // create edit
      hEdit := CreateWindow ('EDIT', 'Hello',
    WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or WS_TABSTOP or WS_BORDER,
    10, 10, 250, 24, hWnd, id_Edit, hInstance, nil) ;

      SetWindowText( hEdit, oh..yea...');
      end;
    WM_COMMAND:
      if LoWord (wParam) = id_Button then
        if HiWord (wParam) = bn_Clicked then
        begin
          GetMem(p, 32*1024); // Подготовка буфера
          GetWindowText(hMemo, p, 32*1024);
          Move(#13#10, PChar(Integer(p) + Length(p))^, 2);
          GetWindowText(hEdit, PChar(Integer(p + Length(p))), 32*1024);
          SetWindowText(hMemo, p);
          while (LOWORD(SendMessage(hMemo, EM_SCROLL, SB_PAGEDOWN,0))<> 0) do;
          FreeMem(p); // Освобождение буфера
        end;
  end;
  Result := DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;


procedure WinMain;
var
  hWnd: THandle;
  Msg: TMsg;
  WndClassEx: TWndClassEx;
begin
  // Инициализировать структуру класса окна
  WndClassEx.cbSize := sizeOf (TWndClassEx);
  WndClassEx.lpszClassName := 'TaskWindow';
  WndClassEx.style := cs_VRedraw or cs_HRedraw;
  WndClassEx.hInstance := HInstance;
  WndClassEx.lpfnWndProc := @WindowProc;
  WndClassEx.cbClsExtra := 0;
  WndClassEx.cbWndExtra := 0;
  WndClassEx.hIcon := LoadIcon (hInstance,
    MakeIntResource ('MAINICON'));
  WndClassEx.hIconSm  := LoadIcon (hInstance,
    MakeIntResource ('MAINICON'));
  WndClassEx.hCursor := LoadCursor (0, idc_Arrow);;
  WndClassEx.hbrBackground := GetStockObject (white_Brush);
  WndClassEx.lpszMenuName := nil;
  // Зарегистрировать класс
  if RegisterClassEx (WndClassEx) = 0 then
    MessageBox (0, 'Invalid class registration',
      'Task API', MB_OK)
  else
  begin
    hWnd := CreateWindowEx (
      ws_Ex_OverlappedWindow, 
      WndClassEx.lpszClassName, 
      'PLSKLLM', 
      ws_OverlappedWindow, 
      cw_UseDefault, 0, 
      cw_UseDefault, 0, 
      0, 
      0, 
      HInstance, 
      nil); 
    if hWnd = 0 then
      MessageBox (0, 'Window not created',
        'Task API', MB_OK)
    else
    begin
      ShowWindow (hWnd, sw_ShowNormal);
      while GetMessage (Msg, 0, 0, 0) do
      begin
        TranslateMessage (Msg);
        DispatchMessage (Msg);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  WinMain;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Замените ^Char на PChar и перепишите Move, там какое-то непотребство.